Upload logs from fluentbit to Opentelemetry collector
I want to upload logs from fluent bit to open telemetry collector on AKS cluster
So, I have installed otel collector as deployment from here
and fluentbit from here
This is my fluentbit configration for output to OTel
[OUTPUT]
     Name                 opentelemetry
     Match                *
     Host                 http://my-opentelemetry-collector.namespace.svc.cluster.local
     Port                 4318
     Metrics_uri          /v1/metrics
     Logs_uri             /v1/logs
     Traces_uri           /v1/traces
     Log_response_payload True
     Tls                  On
     Tls.verify           Off

I have also added environment variable in fluentbit Daemonset
env:
  - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT
    value: http://my-opentelemetry-collector.namespace.svc.cluster.local:4318

But I am getting below error, in my fluentbit logs
[error] [tls] error: unexpected EOF
[2024/07/17 13:51:23] [error] [output:opentelemetry:opentelemetry.1] no upstream connections available to my-opentelemetry-collector.namespace.svc.cluster.local:4317
[2024/07/17 13:51:23] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1721224282.439304987.flb', retry in 7 seconds: task_id=8, input=tail.0 > output=opentelemetry.1 (out_id=1)
[2024/07/17 13:51:23] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1721224282.536490801.flb', retry in 9 seconds: task_id=9, input=tail.0 > output=opentelemetry.1 (out_id=1)

Do I need to make any configuration change in Otel configmap or fluentbit to make this work?
Question asked on Opentelemetry Github
I have tried adding Otel service endpoint in OUTPUT configuration of Fluentbit
I also added the env variable in fluentbit daemonset
But nothing is working.
I want to execute below flow
Logs -> Fluentbit -> OTel Collector -> Uptrace
                                    -> Jaeger
                                    -> etc..

